# Can anyone tell if i can flash javascript code on wemos d1 mini?

Tags: javascript, iot, esp8266, espruino

I am trying to figure out whether I can run javascript code on wemos d1 mini with esp-8266 chip, I was able to find resources on Arduino but not on wemos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you can run JS by installing the Espruino JS interpreter. The D1 mini is just an ESP8266 so you can follow the instructions for that: http://www.espruino.com/EspruinoESP8266

There are a bunch of tutorials and videos online as well that may be clearer. They're pretty easy to find just by searching for "Espruino ESP8266", or there's an ESP8266 section on the Espruino forum that may have help.

Other JS interpreters are available for ESP8266 too (eg. Mongoose IoT) but I believe you will find Espruino easier to get started with (I am however a bit biased as I work on it).